# Return index of selected series

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, charts, line

is there a simple way to get the index of a selected line in a Excel chart using VBA? I have a chart, where the user selects a series. Then a macro should do some thing. I'm looking for something like `idx = Selection.getIndex`.

I need this idx to call other functions which do some stuff with the series using the index to select the specific series (e.g. `FullSeriesCollection(idx).DataLabels.labelPos=...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ideas for you:

**1st- use object variable instead of index reference:**

```
Dim SER As Series
Set SER = Selection
SER.anyproperty.anymethod... 'do your action here
```

**2nd- use plot order to get...index (but not sure if this always match)?**

```
Dim inxSer As Integer
inxSer = Selection.PlotOrder
```

**3rd- read last parameter of series formula**

```
Dim inxFromFormula As Integer
Dim tmpSerFormula As String
tmpSerFormula = Selection.Formula

tmpSerFormula = Mid(tmpSerFormula, InStrRev(tmpSerFormula, ",") + 1)
inxFromFormula = Left(tmpSerFormula, Len(tmpSerFormula) - 1)
```

Comment: The first option here is probably most robust and most useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize Chart object events to achieve that. If the Chart is embedded in a sheet, you need to declare it as 'WithEvents' variable first as described here:
[Using Events with Embedded Charts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211434%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

After that you can define SeriesChange handler with the following parameters:

```
Private Sub myChartClass_SeriesChange(ByVal SeriesIndex As Long, ByVal PointIndex As Long)

End Sub
```

EDIT: The above event is fired when user changes point value, you should use Select event instead.

```
myChartClass_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
```

[Parameter description (the same as BeforeDoubleClick)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/ff197223(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I have a very detailed tutorial about Chart Events at http://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/